# Ansible vars not substituting variables inside dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have the following variable and dictionary :

```
My_VAR1: "Hello"
My_VAR2: "My_DIC1"
My_DIC1: 
   key1: "{{ My_VAR1 }} World"
My_VAR3: "{{ vars[My_VAR2]['key1'] }}"
```

But its seems vars do not substitute the variable , i get the following output :

```
TASK [output : {{ My_VAR1 }} World] ***
```

Is there a way to force vars to substitute the variable and get the following output :

```
TASK [output : Hello World] ***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Is there a way to force vars to substitute the variable and get the following output"*

```
TASK [output : Hello World]
```

A: The play below

```
  vars:
    My_VAR1: Hello
    My_VAR2: "{{ My_VAR1 }} World"
    My_VAR3: "{{ My_VAR2 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: My_VAR3
```

gives

```
"My_VAR3": "Hello World"
```

---

> Q: *"My_VAR2 is a dictionary ..."*

A: Use *lookup* with *vars* plugin. The play below gives the same result.

```
  vars:
    My_VAR1: Hello
    My_DIC1:
      key1: "{{ My_VAR1 }} World"
    My_VAR2: "My_DIC1"
    My_VAR3: "{{ lookup('vars', My_VAR2).key1 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: My_VAR3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my My_VAR2 is a dictionary initially and its not working, i update my question.

Comment: thank you for the answer, its working fine now thank you so much, but its weird, do you have a documentation to read to master this ?

Comment: Sure. Here is the list of the [plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/plugins.html). You're welcome.